# django print form errors in template

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a `forms.Form`

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(" The two password didn't match")

        return password2
```

In my view I am checking for duplicate username or email.

```
if User.objects.filter(Q(username=username) | Q(email=user_email)).exists():
    raise ValidationError("Username or email exist")
```

Now this error is not showing in form. Its showing on my browser when debug is true. 
I dont want to use model form.

Need suggeston how to print this error in form

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all validation logic inside Form class. That's exactly the purpose of Forms layer in django.

You can override clean method to get access to both username and passwords fields data:

```
def clean(self):
   cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
   username = cleaned_data['username']
   user_email = cleaned_data['email']
   if User.objects.filter(Q(username=username) | Q(email=user_email)).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Username or email exist")
```

Any errors raised by your Form.clean() will not be associated with any field in particular. Probably, you need to add {{ forms.non_field_errors }} to list such errors in template

Read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/